# How to find number of occurences of specific distances in binary (search) trees?

Tags: nodes, binary-search-tree, distance, probability, counting

I want to calculate the amount of tree structures that have a given maximal distance between two nodes given an amount `n` of nodes (or keys).

E.g. with `n = 3` there are 5 tree structures, each forced to have a maximal distance of two.
With `n = 4` I can build 14 structures, only 2 of which have a maximal distance of two. The other 12 have a maximal distance of 3.

Now, generalizing the question:

Is there a way to compute the amount of tree structures with a maximal distance `d` given `n` nodes?
And what's the total probability that when given a (uniformly) random permutation of keys to be inserted in the empty tree leads to one of the structures with maximal distance `d`?

Comment: I believe Cormen shows that a randomly generated tree has average height of `O(log(n))` so that probability must become pretty small pretty fast when increasing `d` over about `k*log(n)` for some constant `k`. The proof of this may give some insight on how to compute that probability.

Comment: Note that this question would probably receive better answers on Computer Science SE instead of StackOverflow.